# String Comparision - Performance

Tags: .net, string, compare

Hopefully someone can help me with the following question.

The following sample is given:

The questions are:
1) Why is a compare with Ordinal slower?
2) Why is the same Application with .NET 3.5 instead of .NET 4.5 approx. 10 time faster?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        string longString1 = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(x => (char)r.Next('A', 'z')));
        string longString2 = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(x => (char)r.Next('A', 'z')));

        IsEqualIgnoreCasing(longString1, longString2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void IsEqualIgnoreCasing(string longString1, string longString2)
    {
        CompareWithToUpper(longString1, longString2);
        CompareWithToLower(longString1, longString2);
        ComapreWithEquals(longString1, longString2);
        ComapreWithEqualsOrdinal(longString1, longString2);
    }

    private static void ComapreWithEqualsOrdinal(string longString1, string longString2)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        if (string.Equals(longString1, longString2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Equals Ordinal:".PadRight(30) + watch.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void ComapreWithEquals(string longString1, string longString2)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        if (string.Equals(longString1, longString2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Equals:".PadRight(30) + watch.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void CompareWithToLower(string longString1, string longString2)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        if (longString1.ToLower() == longString2.ToLower())
        {
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ToLower:".PadRight(30) + watch.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void CompareWithToUpper(string longString1, string longString2)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        if (longString1.ToUpper() == longString2.ToUpper())
        {
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ToUpper:".PadRight(30) + watch.Elapsed);
    }
```

Comment: Is this a real problem or theoretical?  Not  sure of the 3.5 vs 4.5 differences, but I can't remember the last time I wanted to do a direct string comparison of 10K length strings, let alone 10M.

Comment: It is more theoretical. But MSDN states for example that Ordinal Compare is always the fastest option - not in this case.
And especially the big difference between the 3.x and 4.x CLR makes me scare...

Comment: May need insiders at Microsoft to know for sure.  But I could see them, optimizing 4.5 in the general case that might have a high cost for exceedingly long strings.  Always and never often turn out to be approximations :)